# What is happening when docker-maven plugin tries to build image?

Tags: maven, plugins, jenkins, permissions, docker

I am running Jenkins in a docker container and Jenkins tries to run my maven build. As part of the build, the docker maven plugin instructs it to build a docker image.

That part of the POM is below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <imageName>example</imageName>
        <baseImage>java:latest</baseImage>
        <skipDockerBuild>false</skipDockerBuild>
        <cmd>["java", "-jar", "myLogThread-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]</cmd>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/</directory>
                <include>config.properties</include>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                <include>myLogThread-jar-with-dependencies.jar</include>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The maven build runs until it attempts to build the image, at which point the following error message is spat out:

```
[INFO] Building image example
[INFO] I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: Permission denied
```

I can go into the correct directory and the Dockerfile is there.

I can also run `sudo docker build .` and it will build the image with no issues.

Why is the maven build failing? What request is being made to localhost:80? How can I correct this so that maven can build my image?

Note: I have mounted the docker socket and binary in this container

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Try adding `DOCKER_OPTS=' -G jenkins'` directly in /etc/default/docker. Then restart docker service by `sudo service docker restart`

Comment: I am having the same issue with exactly same environment. Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above by Rajith Delantha, this solved the problem for me:

Add: `DOCKER_OPTS=' -G jenkins'` directly in `/etc/default/docker`.

Then restart docker service by `sudo service docker restart`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be resolved by adding `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable in Jenkins.

Setup your docker daemon like this:

```
[/etc/sysconfig/docker]
OPTIONS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243"
```

Jenkins Jobs (Inject environment variables):

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:4243
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but in my local machine.

I've got it after reading this comment in Github thread: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1214#issuecomment-256774629

It says:

> Solution (from
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/, does not
>   only work with Debian):
>
> Add the docker group if it doesn't already exist.
>
> `sudo groupadd docker`
>
> Add the connected user "${USER}" to the docker group. Change the user
>   name to match your preferred user. You may have to logout and log back
>   in again for this to take effect.
>
> `sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker`
>
> Restart the Docker daemon.
>
> `sudo service docker restart`

Answer (score 1):

after making sure `docker ps` works from the same user that runs `mvn` I still had the same problem.
it looks like a bug due to special characters in the image name. I resolved it by removing the dash sign (-) (or any special characters) from the docker image name.

try set the repository to deferent name and check.

```
            <configuration>
                <repository>somename</repository>                    
            </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by combining elements of both upvoted answers.

Set options to use different port in `/etc/default/docker`.

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243"
```

Restart the Docker daemon.

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Then build your package.

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:4243
mvn clean package docker:build
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the issue at bamboo-agent, but I assume the same holds for jenkins.

Add the user running maven to the docker group. Then restart docker AND the service running maven. Group changes are not loaded while the services are running. So in my case:

```
sudo groupadd docker # if it does not exist
sudo usermod -a -G docker bamboo-user
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
sudo systemctl restart bamboo-agent.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I didn't have the docker daemon running - restart the Docker toolbox and it looks much happier now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Jenkins.

Added jenkins to docker group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

Then restrat jenkins.