# INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: Permission denied

Tags: docker, jhipster

when try to build a Docker image of a jhipster application on Ubuntu. got error:

```
INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
Jan 12, 2017 11:45:49 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: Permission denied
Jan 12, 2017 11:45:49 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:19 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-12T11:45:49-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 77M/730M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default-cli) on project poetry: Exception caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Permission denied -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Try running maven with ` --debug` flag to see if you get more details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is happening when docker-maven plugin tries to build image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748584/what-is-happening-when-docker-maven-plugin-tries-to-build-image)

Answer (score 1):

I am using VS Code.
I am running docker on the root using this command line:

```
sudo docker run -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin:2.23
```

To build an image of my microservice, I run the following comand line on the root as well:

```
sudo mvn spring-boot:build-image -DskipTests
```

This worked for me and I hope it helps someone some other day.

Answer (score 0):

add docker permission to your jhipster application user group
or
Try adding DOCKER_OPTS=' -G ' directly in /etc/default/docker. Then restart docker service by sudo service docker restart

Answer (score 0):

export the docker_host environment variablin the terminal

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this error when docker was running from root user and your mvn build command is running on normal user. I tried running sudo wit mvn docker:build and it got successful.